# jQuery one page scrolling site - animated deep linking

Tags: jquery, scroll, animated, deep-linking

I'm working on a one page scrolling site (with a sticky header) and want to add animated deep linking.

You can view the demo here:
http://www.creativecontroller.com/demo/onepage/

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:
- click on nav link, animate to div - in this case I'm using html5 sections (Done)
- have the hashtag displayed in the url like ...demo/onepage/#about
- if the user clicks another link, it animates, updates the url hashtag and animates to the right div
- if the user clicks the back button it animates back to the previous div instead of just snapping to it
- try to do this without using any plugins (just jQuery)

Here's the jQuery I'm using for the page scrolling and sticky header:

```
// Page scrolling
$(function() {
    $('a').bind('click',function(event){
        var $anchor = $(this);

        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top - 60
        }, 1500,'easeInOutExpo');

        event.preventDefault();
    });
});


// Sticky Nav
$(window).scroll(function(e) {
    var nav_anchor = $(".nav_anchor").offset().top;

    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= nav_anchor && $('.nav').css('position') != 'fixed') 
    {    
        $('.nav').css({
            'position': 'fixed',
            'top': '0px'
        });

        $('.nav_anchor').css('height', '60px');
    } 
    else if ($(this).scrollTop() < nav_anchor && $('.nav').css('position') != 'relative') 
    {   

        $('.nav_anchor').css('height', '0px');

        $('.nav').css({
            'position': 'relative'
        });
    }
});
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

UPDATE:
I found a site that does what I've described above:
http://www.maddim.com/demos/spark-r6/

Comment: where's the question? sounds like you want someone to code a complete UI for you

Comment: The question would be: Can someone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, change your anchor tags from absolute to relative URL's (`href="#about"` rather than `href="http://blahfdsjkld.com#about"`). Then update your function like so:

```
// Page scrolling
$(function() {
    $('a').bind('click',function(event){

        // Do this first
        event.preventDefault();

        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top - 60
        }, 1500,'easeInOutExpo');

        // Use an id that isn't on the page, hence the capitalization of the first letter
        window.location.hash = $anchor.html().charAt(0).toUpperCase() + $anchor.html().slice(1);
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi NBSP, thanks for your help but adding the 2 lines of code you suggested makes the whole page just jump a few pixels at a time.
Could this be due to the page being told to jump directly to the anchor before the animation function has completed? Does it override it somehow?

Comment: Yes, I think you're exactly correct. I would add the `window.location.hash = $anchor.haml();` line to jQuery `.anmiate()`'s `complete` callback.

Comment: I know where you're going with this but once I do that it just finished the animation then jumps to the anchor. This does do something similar to what I was after but once you click the back button it jumps to the last anchor instead of animating to it.

This site does what I'm after:
http://www.maddim.com/demos/spark-r6/

And once again, thanks for your time :)

Comment: I have updated my answer. It doesn't deal with scrolling with the back button (it just jumps to the section), but the rest should be covered.

Comment: @nbsp do absolute urls not work? Wouldn't that be better for SEO if it's possible?